# Additional section in UITableView with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently implementing a UITableViewController with an NSFetchedResultsController. It fetches some objects from CoreData and displays them as rows in one section as expected.

Now, I would like to have one additional section with exactly one row that displays aggregated information about the fetched objects.

From what I know, one NSFetchedResultsController can only have one fetch request, but I would have to use another one to get the aggregated information.

Perhaps I should use one NSFetchedResultsController for the Overall section and another one for the single object section, but this feels kind of strange to me.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use one fetchedResultController. And add some observer functions in the delegate of fetchedResultController:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller{
[self updateAggregatedInformation : basedOnFecthedObjects]; //with collection keypath methods;
[self updateTableView];
```

}

There is a little overhead in the tableView DataSource, but gain in performance.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. From my point of view the problem is that I would like to display more sections (2) than my fetchedResultsController provides (1). I moved the fetched result to section with index 1 and the summary cell is supposed to be at section index 0. I am not even able to display the table because the following exception is raised: 

2018-10-18 07:51:58.937319+0200 MyApp[84366:14359728] [error] error: NSFetchedResultsController: no section at index 1 in sections list
CoreData: error: NSFetchedResultsController: no section at index 1 in sections list

Comment: Perhaps I should simply put two tables into the view so that they are completely independent from each other.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem and it was more easy than I thought.

The NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate receives messages from the FRC and so the delivered IndexPath.section attributes have be adapted according to the tableView. The same needs to be done the other way around when the tableView calls the FRC to create cells that are backed up by the fetched entities.